# How to initialize a union of pointers to nullptr?

Tags: c++, unions

Assume I have a C++ class like this:

```
class Container
{
private:
  union {
    Foo* foo;
    Bar* bar;
  } mPtr;
};
```

This class will be constructed on the stack. I.e. it won't be `new`ed, so I can't just declare a zeroing `operator new`.

Can I use the initializer in the constructor to set `mPtr` to `nullptr` somehow?

```
Container()
 : mPtr(nullptr)
{
}
```

does not compile. Not even by adding a dummy `union` member of type `nullptr_t`.

```
Container()
 : mPtr.foo(nullptr)
{
}
```

doesn't compile, either.

Comment: try `: mPtr(NULL)`, you can also define a constructor for the union. For this it has to be named though AFAIK

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use aggregate initialization, for example:

```
Container() : mPtr { nullptr }
{ }
```

I don't normally like posting links, but [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is a good run through of this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the compiler you are using. This should work, but VS 2013 does not support it.

```
Container(): mPtr{nullptr}
{
}
```

This does work however:

```
union {
   int* foo {nullptr};
   double* bar;
} mPtr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just default-initialise it.

```
Container()
 : mPtr()
{
}
```